# Mockito Test for JDBC Template Query

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is the test case I have written test case

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(),Matchers.any(RowMapper.class)).thenReturn(B));
```

for below code

```
List<B> b = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL,(resultSet,i) -> {
B b = new B();
b.setId(resultSet.getString("ID"));
b.setMobile(resultSet.getString("Mobile"));
return b;
});
```

Earlier the error which was coming it was due to import, it was using hamcrest instead of Mockito.Now it's throwing **NULLPointer Exception** at the jdbcTemplate.query()
Can someone please help me where I am going wrong with this test case?

Comment: Just a comment. Mocking classes you don't own is a known anti-pattern that can cause the test to be a lot more complex. My suggestion is to know use a unit test for a class that connects to an external system, but do an integration test, maybe using an in-memory DB like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

Comment: Please show entire error message. (I mean, types of arguments. Did you get your imports right for `any()`?)

Comment: The error was coming due to import, it has taken hamcrest instead of Mockito.

Comment: What is `jdbcTemplate`?